# Render partial view using multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to render partial `<div>` on clicking any one button among multiple button.

partial content:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="partial">
    Some Partial content
</div>
```

buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="show-partial">Button1</button>
<button type="button" id="show-partial">Button2</button>
<button type="button" id="show-partial">Button3</button>
```

javascript:

```
$('#show-partial').click(function(){
    $('#partial').show();
});
```

In this code partial is render only click on first button, not render on clicking other buttons

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document. Change `id="show-partial"` to `class="show-partial"` and `$('#show-partial')` to `$('.show-partial')`, for example.

Comment: That is because `jQuery` matches only the 1st encountered element with the `ID` and discards all the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the same id more than once.

Check the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).

Instead use classes:

```
<button type="button" class="show-partial">Button1</button>
<button type="button" class="show-partial">Button2</button>
<button type="button" class="show-partial">Button3</button>
```

And then assign the click listener to that class:

```
$('.show-partial').on('click', function() {
   $('#partial').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

each element should have `unique id` not all have `show-partial`. you can instead `class` like

```
<button type="button" class="show-partial">Button1</button>
<button type="button" class="show-partial">Button2</button>
<button type="button" class="show-partial">Button3</button>  
$('.show-partial').click(function(){
    $('#partial').show();
});
```

`$('#partial').show();` is shown when you click on any of button what why there is no effect.